# Cannot use get_ports() with stem modules

Tags: python, stem

I am unable to use the function `get_ports()` with `stem`. It says

```
# python get_ports.py OR
[...]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/socket.py", line 126, in send
raise stem.SocketClosed()
```

`get_ports.py` contains the following:

```
import stem
from stem.control import Controller
import sys

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
controller.authenticate()  # provide the password here if you set one
print controller.get_ports('OR')
```

I am certain my control port is open. My `torrc` has the following non-commented lines:

```
CookieAuthentication 1
ControlPort 9051
StrictNodes 1
```

**Why can't I connect to my control port and how to execute the `get_ports()` function properly?**

---

PS (full output)

```
# python get_ports.py                                     [git][stem/controller][master]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_ports.py", line 11, in <module>
    print controller.get_ports('OR')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/control.py", line 454, in wrapped
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/control.py", line 1302, in get_ports
    return [port for (addr, port) in self.get_listeners(listener_type) if addr == '127.0.0.1']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/control.py", line 454, in wrapped
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/control.py", line 1334, in get_listeners
    for listener in self.get_info(query).split():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/control.py", line 454, in wrapped
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/control.py", line 1162, in get_info
    response = self.msg('GETINFO %s' % ' '.join(params))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/control.py", line 627, in msg
    self._socket.send(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/socket.py", line 126, in send
    raise stem.SocketClosed()
stem.SocketClosed
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
$ pip2 show stem
---
Name: stem
Version: 1.5.1
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: 
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from stem.control import Controller
>>> with Controller.from_port(port = 9151) as controller:
...  controller.authenticate()
...  print controller.get_ports('OR')
... 
[]
>>> with Controller.from_port(port = 9151) as controller:
...  controller.authenticate()
...  print controller.get_ports('CONTROL')
... 
[9151]
```

Are you running this under Tails, Whonix, Subgraph or a similar operating system which uses a control port filter as a security mechanism?

The connection is being terminated from somewhere outside after the GETINFO request is sent, as shown by the [`stem.SocketClosed`](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html#stem.SocketClosed) exception being raised, which took all of 1 minute to find. You should familiarize yourself with utilizing the documentation of libraries if you intend to write code, it is an invaluable skill.

Answer (score 0):

Your Tor config states that you're using cookie-based authentication, but you're using just `authenticate()` instead of `authenticate_cookie()` - see the [documentation](https://stem.torproject.org/_modules/stem/connection.html)